# Returning a promise inside promise (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it a good practice to use promises inside a promise?
Thank you.

Comment: You can see this: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no problem using promises inside promises, it is even required sometimes to create fully asynchronous scripts.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to chain the promises, you can create another promise inside the .then() function and return it. so that way you can chain the .then() functions, like this:

```
getUserPromise().then(doSomethingFunction).then(doSomethingElseFunction)
```